# Second image not displaying when clicked in GuiApp, no one can figure out why?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jbutton

```
public class Memory extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2065145900871059367L;
private JPanel contentPane;
public static void main(String[] args) { //auto generated from WindowBuilder
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Memory frame = new Memory();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
JButton[] cards = new JButton[12];
int [] flippedNum = new int[12];
Icon [] catImg = new Icon[12];
{
catImg[0]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("2faceszd.jpg"));
catImg[1] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("blkctszd.jpg"));
catImg[2]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ct&mszd.png"));
catImg[3]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("floofctszd.jpg"));
catImg[4]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("orngctszd.jpg"));
catImg[5]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("siamctszd.jpg"));
catImg[6]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("2faceszd.jpg"));
catImg[7] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("blkctszd.jpg"));
catImg[8]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ct&mszd.png"));
catImg[9]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("floofctszd.jpg"));
catImg[10]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("orngctszd.jpg"));
catImg[11]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("siamctszd.jpg"));
} //6 images added twice
Icon photo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("BG.png"));

static List<Integer> cats = new ArrayList<Integer>();{
    cats.add(1); cats.add(1);
    cats.add(2); cats.add(2);
    cats.add(3); cats.add(3);
    cats.add(4); cats.add(4);
    cats.add(5); cats.add(5);
    cats.add(6); cats.add(6);
}

static Random kitty = new Random();
public static int getCardAssignment(){
    int cat = kitty.nextInt(cats.size());
    int ucat = cats.get(cat);
    cats.remove(cat);
    return ucat;
} returns a random number to be assigned to an icon
 //building the frame
public Memory() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 650, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel title = new JPanel();
    title.setName("");
    title.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    title.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    contentPane.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel gameName = new JLabel("Memory Game");
    title.add(gameName);
    gameName.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    gameName.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    gameName.setEnabled(false);

    JPanel cardDisplay = new JPanel();
    cardDisplay.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    cardDisplay.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    cardDisplay.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    contentPane.add(cardDisplay, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    cardDisplay.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4, 10, 10));        

    ButtonClickEventHandler clickIt = new ButtonClickEventHandler();

    for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i ++){
        cards[i] = new JButton(); // new button
        flippedNum[i] = getCardAssignment(); //card# assigned to cat icon
        cards[i].setIcon(photo); //set background image
        cards[i].addActionListener(clickIt); //when you click it
        cardDisplay.add(cards[i]); //show them all
        System.out.println("background displayed"); 
         //sysprint statements are for testing the output stream only   
        }
    }
    private class ButtonClickEventHandler implements ActionListener{
private int q = 0; //# of clickes, like switch statement w/o userinput
private int l; // = 0; records number location when clicked
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i ++){
if (q == 0){ //at zero all enabled cards/buttons are face up
    if(cards[i] == e.getSource()){//first card clicked //start state
        System.out.println("q is 0");
        System.out.println("Selection was number " + i);
        l = i; // record the click for the next state. 
            //sets the icon to a cat image w/num [flipped num]
        cards[i].setEnabled(false); 
    // prevents user from clicking the same card twice for a match
        cards[i].setIcon(catImg[flippedNum[i]])
        cards[i].setDisabledIcon(catImg[flippedNum[i]]); 
  //prevents the icon from being grayed out when clicked
            //setting the icon and THEN the disabled icon shows 
            //non gray'd out image when clicked that cannot be clicked again
        q = 1;
        System.out.println("q is now 1");
    }
}
else if(q == 1) { //if one card is already clicked, second click
    System.out.println("q was not 0, now is 1");        
        if(cards[i] == e.getSource()){
            cards[i].setIcon(catImg[flippedNum[i]]);
        System.out.println("first was " + flippedNum[l] + " Second was " + flippedNum[i]); 
            cards[i].setIcon(catImg[flippedNum[i]]);            
            q = 2;
        }
        if(q == 2){
            System.out.println("Timer started");
            cards[l].doClick(1500); 
      //i tried moving this up to before q=2, no luck
        if(flippedNum[l] == flippedNum[i]){
            System.out.println("They Match!!");
            cards[i].setEnabled(false); 
       // permanenty sets the button as disabled
            cards[l].setEnabled(false);
            q=0;
            System.out.println("end of turn q is zero, find another match");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Dont Match");
                cards[i].setEnabled(true);
                cards[l].setEnabled(true);
                cards[i].setIcon(photo);
                cards[l].setIcon(photo);
                q = 0;
            System.out.println("end of turn, back to start, q = 0");
            }
        }
}
}
}
```

}
}

The code SHOULD let the user click on one image where it is displayed and disabled so you can't click it a second time and match it to itself. the second click SHOULD reveal the second card (it doesn't) and start the timer (it does)
with in the q=2 section, the match check is still preformed on the image the user can't see and the timer still flips the first card back over after 1500mills. and if there is a match both cards should stay image side up (it does) and grayed out (it doesn't unless i remove the cards[i].setEnabled, even the previously unseen card turns gray when the .setEnabled is off in the q=0 statement)

- I've had teachers, tutors, and friends look over this without any progress, PLEASE help. ty.

  - - SAMPLE OUTPUT:
  - background displayed
  - // this is printed 12 times
  - //once for each card
  - Selection was number 1 // selected the 4th card in the first row
  - q is now 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - //selected the second card in the first row which did not "Show"
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - first was 6 Second was 1
  - Timer started
  - Don't Match// first card flipped back to background after 1.5 seconds
  - end of turn, back to start, q = 0
  - q is 0
  - Selection was number 2 // selected 3rd card in first row
  - q is now 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - q was not 0, now is 1
  - first was 6 Second was 6 // second image selected, didn't show
  - Timer started
  - They Match!! // both images are revealed! neither is gray'd out
  - end of turn q is zero, find another match

Comment: if you fix your indentation, someone may help you

Comment: `cards[l].doClick(1500);` this isn't doing what you think it is

Answer (score 0):

Basically, based on your code `doClick(long)` will make the button appear pressed, it will not delay the code and will cause `actionPerformed` to be called again ... when you really don't want it to be.

The solution you seem to be looking for is a Swing `Timer`, see [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

I butchered your code a little to get "something" working, it will at least display the second card 1.5 seconds.

```
private class ButtonClickEventHandler implements ActionListener {

    private int q = 0; //# of clickes, like switch statement w/o userinput
    private int l; // = 0; records number location when clicked

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if (q == 0) { //at zero all enabled cards/buttons are face up
                if (cards[i] == e.getSource()) {//first card clicked //start state
                    System.out.println("q is 0");
                    System.out.println("Selection was number " + i);
                    l = i; // record the click for the next state. 
                    //sets the icon to a cat image w/num [flipped num]
                    cards[i].setEnabled(false);
                    // prevents user from clicking the same card twice for a match
                    cards[i].setIcon(catImg[flippedNum[i]]);
                    cards[i].setDisabledIcon(catImg[flippedNum[i]]);
                    //prevents the icon from being grayed out when clicked
                    //setting the icon and THEN the disabled icon shows 
                    //non gray'd out image when clicked that cannot be clicked again
                    q = 1;
                    System.out.println("q is now 1");
                    break;
                }
            } else if (q == 1) { //if one card is already clicked, second click
                System.out.println("q was not 0, now is 1");
                if (cards[i] == e.getSource()) {
                    cards[i].setIcon(catImg[flippedNum[i]]);
                    System.out.println("first was " + flippedNum[l] + " Second was " + flippedNum[i]);

                    flipFlop(l, i);
                    q = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void flipFlop(int l, int i) {

        Timer timer = new Timer(1500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Timer started");
                //cards[l].doClick(1500);
                //i tried moving this up to before q=2, no luck
                if (flippedNum[l] == flippedNum[i]) {
                    System.out.println("They Match!!");
                    cards[i].setEnabled(false);
                    // permanenty sets the button as disabled
                    cards[l].setEnabled(false);
                    System.out.println("end of turn q is zero, find another match");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Dont Match");
                    cards[i].setEnabled(true);
                    cards[l].setEnabled(true);
                    cards[i].setIcon(photo);
                    cards[l].setIcon(photo);
                    System.out.println("end of turn, back to start, q = 0");
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

You `actionPerformed` method could use a little more optimising, once you have established some action, you should `break` out of the loop, as no further processing should be done, let's face it, once you know which button was clicked and if it was the first or second button, why should you keep iterating?

Comment: oh thank you! I cannot tell you the headache this has been, in a previous version i had tried the Timer, but I think i might have been importing the wrong one, not Swing. the do(click) would at least pause something, Thread.sleep, and the java.util timer were useless. the only thing that's off is  the "grayed out" images. sometimes it will gray out only one and other times it won't gray out any, but I think i can figure that one out. thank you again. so much